# React Native Build Errors on IOS

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile

I'm writing an app for mobile devices, phones, tablets etc. Yet after experiencing some issues on an Ipad emulator, I researched a few fixes and came across a post where it said to open Xcode, navigate to the Build Settings Tab and then search for the Targeted Device Family and change to Ipad and Iphone. After doing so I am now stuck with a build error when running `npx react-native run-ios` this is the build error I'm getting

````
warning: Run script build phase 'Bundle React Native code and images' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'kidgaurd' from project 'kidgaurd')

```--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:DB863F04-108E-45FB-833D-D7629FE56E1D, OS:17.2, name:iPhone 15 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:DB863F04-108E-45FB-833D-D7629FE56E1D, OS:17.2, name:iPhone 15 Plus }
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/owenburns/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/kidgaurd-bsywdasyedsejugskbcxbafwrlij/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-rncore.build/Script-46EB2E00023610.sh (in target 'React-rncore' from project 'Pods')
        PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Copy\ XCFrameworks /Users/owenburns/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/kidgaurd-bsywdasyedsejugskbcxbafwrlij/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/OpenSSL-Universal.build/Script-46EB2E00023600.sh (in target 'OpenSSL-Universal' from project 'Pods')
        PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Copy\ XCFrameworks /Users/owenburns/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/kidgaurd-bsywdasyedsejugskbcxbafwrlij/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Glog.build/Script-46EB2E000235F0.sh (in target 'Flipper-Glog' from project 'Pods')
        PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Copy\ XCFrameworks /Users/owenburns/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/kidgaurd-bsywdasyedsejugskbcxbafwrlij/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-DoubleConversion.build/Script-46EB2E000235E0.sh (in target 'Flipper-DoubleConversion' from project 'Pods')
(4 failures)```

1. Tried cleaning the build folder by going to Product -> Clean Build Folder. Afterwards going to my project directory, deleting the Podfile.lock file as well as the Pods folder. Did a ```pod install``` afterwards and attempted to re-run the app. This attempt Failed.
2. Tried changing the setting ```Targeted Device Families``` back to it's original Iphone selection. This attempt also failed.
````